# No commerce_price field in product after Kickstart

Tags: commerce

I installed Commerce Kickstart 7.x-2.35 and I'm doing a Ubercart Commerce migration (from my current Drupal 6 site) using the Commerce Migrate Ubercart module. When migrating first products I don't see the prices and get an error message:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$commerce_price en
>   commerce_product_line_item_populate() in line 1394 of the
>   commerce_product_reference.module.

During migration the old Ubercart price (`sell_price`) is correctly mapped to `commerce_price`.

When checking Product Display type I don't see any price field, the only fields I see are product title, url, body, category and reference. Should I manually add a price field `commerce_price`? How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The commerce_price field should be on products referenced by the display. Typically what happens is an importer will migrate all product entities first (which corresponds to each SKU in the remote system) and then set the product reference field value of a product display to point to those product entities. The SKU is unique, so it can be used as unique ID to reference displays to SKUs when you don't actually know product IDs.

Comment: Thanks Ryan,but still struggling. In CommerceMigrateUbercart config I get:
"commerce_price" was used as destination field in "sell_price" mapping but is not in list of destination fields
"commerce_price:currency_code" was used as destination field in "" mapping but is not in list of destination fields
I guess I need to add commerce_price field to product display,but I don't know how.I can't in views (backoffice product or product variations),product display or any place.The parameter isn't there & can't be added (many other are there).
I'm Commerce newbee,please explain in a simple way.Thanks!